# How to copy a file in Maven only when it has changed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm developing a web application in Java, using Tomcat, Maven and Eclipse.

In order to manually test the application while I develop, I'm using Maven to copy some files to the right place in Tomcat. These files are not dependencies, just Tomcat configuration files I have in a local directory.

I'm copying them using the `copy-rename-maven-plugin` in the `process-resources` phase, so the files are in place for launching Tomcat manually, after compilation.

The problem I'm facing is that touching some files (`context.xml` and `server.xml`), even without modifying them makes tomcat restart.

The ideal solution would be to configure `copy-rename-maven-plugin` to only overwrite a file if it has changed (or if it's newer) but it seems that it's not possible. So far I have been able to set overwrite to no, but then if there's a change in the original file is not going to be copied because the destination file already exists.

Comment: Maybe with the maven antrun plugin you can copy files with more fine-grained control.

Comment: If you use Eclipse's [WTP Server Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/server/server.php) plugin, you don't need to deploy anything with Maven. The files `server.xml` and `context.xml` for example are copied from your `Servers` project to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf` whenever you start the server from Eclipse.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I already tried WTP, but unfortunately the aplication we are using is a complex one where I must deploy 15 WAR files and I have been unable to use WTP. May be I must give it another try.

Comment: @JFabianMeier  I'm trying to avoid Ant to avoid having mixed syntax or additional files. But ant may be the way.